# Creating duplicate lines using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a paint-like program that allows you to draw a single line, which in turn creates a grid of duplicate lines, forming a basic tessellated structure as the end result. I have written a basic program using Tkinter, however, I do not have much experience using Tkinter, or even python for that matter. Currently, I can draw two lines which sit side by side, but are also connected at every new point throughout. I am aware that my code is probably less than stellar (In fact, it is probably quite bad).

EDIT: It wont let me embed images in my posts yet, [so here is a link to a generic, if sloppy, example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up8Dr.png) of what I want the the program to produce.

SECOND EDIT: I've worked some more on my code and slightly improved it, but I am still having an issue with my second and third line instances connecting to the original line:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

lastx, lasty = 0, 0
points = [(100,100),(300,100),(300,300),(100,300)]
c=1

def xy(event):
    global lastx, lasty
    lastx, lasty = event.x, event.y

def xy(event):
    global lastx2, lasty2
    lastx2, lasty2 = event.x+200, event.y+200


def addLine(event):
    global lastx, lasty
    canvas.create_line((lastx, lasty, event.x, event.y))
    lastx, lasty = event.x, event.y

def newLine1(event):
    global lastx2, lasty2
    canvas.create_line((lastx2, lasty2, event.x-200, event.y))
    lastx2, lasty2 = event.x, event.y

def newLine2(event):
    global lastx2, lasty2
    canvas.create_line((lastx2, lasty2, event.x, event.y-200))
    lastx2, lasty2 = event.x, event.y

def LineCreate(event):
    addLine(event)
    newLine1(event)
    newLine2(event)

root = Tk()
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", xy)
canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", LineCreate)
canvas.create_polygon(points, outline='#f11',
            fill='#1f1', width=2)


root.mainloop()
```

OLD CODE
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk

```
lastx, lasty = 0, 0
points = [(100,100),(300,100),(300,300),(100,300)]
c=1

def xy(event):
    global lastx, lasty
    lastx, lasty = event.x, event.y

def xy(event):
    global lastx2, lasty2
    lastx2, lasty2 = event.x+50, event.y+50


def addLine(event):
    global lastx, lasty
    canvas.create_line((lastx, lasty, event.x, event.y))
    lastx, lasty = event.x, event.y

def addLine(event):
    global lastx2, lasty2
    canvas.create_line((lastx2, lasty2, event.x+50*c, event.y))
    lastx2, lasty2 = event.x+5, event.y+5

root = Tk()
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", xy)
canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", addLine)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That's what I originally tried to do, however, it connects the two lines to each other at multiple points. I'm also physically drawing the lines in the canvas after the program is run, not just creating a line from point to point.

Comment: What do you mean by "a grid of duplicate lines"? Could you upload an image of the desired result? I am also confused that your program seems to be a minimalistic version of MS paint. Is this feature just for debugging purposes?

Comment: I am trying to create a paint-like program which creates duplicate lines offset by some number of pixels to the left and above the original line. The intention is to be able to create simple tessellated shapes based around a square by drawing just two sides of the shape. I will try to add a picture of what I want it to create.

Comment: Thanks, that makes you question way more understandable. I suggest that you integrate the content of your last comment into your original question. The key-word "paint-like program" really helps understanding the topic here.

Comment: Your code has two `xy(event)`, only the last one is effective.  And should it be two canvases, one for the drawing and one for the result?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand that you want to repeat the pattern drawn inside the `polygon` region (actually you can use `rectangle` instead of `polygon`), below is an example:

```
def xy(event):
    global lastx, lasty
    lastx, lasty = event.x, event.y

def LineCreate(event):
    global lastx, lasty
    # draw the base pattern
    canvas.create_line((lastx, lasty, event.x, event.y))
    # duplicate the pattern
    repeat = 5
    for row in range(repeat):
        for col in range(repeat):
            if row or col: # don't draw on the original again
                canvas.create_line((lastx+col*200, lasty+row*200, event.x+col*200, event.y+row*200))
    lastx, lasty = event.x, event.y # save the last point
```